# While crawling the data on website using beautiful soup i am facing HTTP 404 and 503 Error

Tags: python-3.7

I am facing the problem while scraping the data from this link:
https://www.yelp.com/user_details_reviews_self?userid=UsXqCXRZwSCSw0AT7y1uBg

I want to crawl all the pages but it gives me error.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = input("Enter the URL : ")
max_pages = int(input("Enter the Maximum Number of Pages you want to Extract : "))

for i in range(1, max_pages+1):
    my_url = url[::-1].replace('1',str(i) ,1)[::-1]
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "review"})
container = containers[0]

for container in containers:
    business_id = container.find_all("a",{'data-analytics-label':'biz- name'})
    bID_count = (business_id[0].attrs['data-hovercard-id'])
    print(bID_count)
```

c:\users\shani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\urllib\request.py 
 in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    501         for handler in handlers:
    502             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
 --> 503             result = func(*args)
    504             if result is not None:
    505                 return result

c:\users\shani\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\urllib\request.py 
 in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the error because of this:

```
my_url = url[::-1].replace('1',str(i) ,1)[::-1]
```

I guess you wanted to change the page number, but what you actually do here is you replacing `1` in User ID thus generating non existing User ID and this causes your 404 error.

You need to change how pagination works in your script. Pay attention to how it actually works on that page:

```
https://www.yelp.com/user_details_reviews_self?userid=UsXqCXRZwSCSw0AT7y1uBg&rec_pagestart=0
```

Your URL misses last part (`&rec_pagestart=0`), which increments in 10s, i.e. 0, 10, 20, 30, etc...

So, you need something like this:

```
url = "https://www.yelp.com/user_details_reviews_self?userid=UsXqCXRZwSCSw0AT7y1uBg&rec_pagestart="
for i in range(max_pages+1):
    my_url = url + str(i*10)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I did this its working now but i am facing "error 503" service is not available on yelp platform when i crawl the data up-to 200 pages. The next user i could not access and they show this error 503.But when i access this url on my browser via VPN then its sshows the content on website but my code shows my the error. After four to five hors i could access the URL but again its service unavailable because of error 503. Can you help me how to fix it trough my code?? Any suggestion?

Comment: Strictly speaking, scraping Yelp violates its' Terms of Service. See [here](https://www.yelp-support.com/article/Can-I-copy-or-scrape-data-from-the-Yelp-site?l=en_GB). And it looks like you are being temporarily banned from using Yelp after extensive scraping. Please, respect their ToS. If you want to properly scrape some other site, then general practices include random time delays between requests, getting pages in random order (not 1,2,3, etc., but 1,7,3,9,2, etc.) and using proxies lists for your requests.

Comment: how to use the proxies lists for request. Can you please amend them in my code???

Comment: Dear @chandbasra, hope this may help: https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-rotate-proxies-and-ip-addresses-using-python-3/

Comment: can you please tell me how could i use proxy to avoid the blockage from web server. In yelp platform the above code i applied the above mentioned method which you suggested me ,it did not work. I will be very thankful to you

Comment: Few comments above I have posted the link to research proxy usage. Hope this may help.

Comment: sie these are not working in my case. any other suggestions please